# How to Change the Color of an Item Immediately in View

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a ListPicker which has a few different options of color values. When a color value is selected, I would like to immediately show that color on some items in the View. I am a little confused on how best to accomplish this though.

EditPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Brush}" Margin="12,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="themeListPicker" Header="Theme" FullModeHeader="Theme" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                                        SelectionChanged="themeListPicker_SelectionChanged"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" 
                                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"/>
```

EditPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        themeList = new List<Theme>();
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Indigo.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "indigo", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 0, 255) });
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cyan.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cyan", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 161, 226) });
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cobalt.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cobalt", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 80, 239) });

        themeListPicker.ItemsSource = themeList;
    }

private void themeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (themeListPicker.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        CurrentTheme = themeListPicker.SelectedItem as Theme;
    }

public class Theme : NotifyingObject
{
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Brush
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        }
    }

    private Theme _currentTheme;
    public Theme CurrentTheme
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentTheme;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == _currentTheme) return;
            _currentTheme = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTheme");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am putting this together correctly. Also, how can I immediately show the currently selected color as the color of an object or some property of an object in the view? I have a couple ToggleSwitches, a Slider bar, etc which should change colors immediately upon selecting a new item in the ListPicker.

EDIT**

EditPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>       
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding CurrentTheme.Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTheme.Name}" Foreground="{Binding CurrentTheme.Brush}" Margin="12,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding CurrentTheme.Image}" Width="50" Height="37.59"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTheme.Name}" Foreground="{Binding CurrentTheme.Brush}" Margin="12,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

..

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="themeListPicker" Header="Theme" FullModeHeader="Theme" 
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                                        SelectionChanged="themeListPicker_SelectionChanged"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" 
                                        FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"/>

<Slider x:Name="Slider"  Minimum="1" Maximum="6" Margin="12,20,12,0" Foreground="{Binding CurrentTheme.Brush}"
                    ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" Value="1"/>
```

EditPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        themeList = new List<Theme>();
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Indigo.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "indigo", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 0, 255) });
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cyan.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cyan", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 161, 226) });
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cobalt.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cobalt", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 80, 239) });

        var viewModel = new ThemeViewModel();
        viewModel.Themes = themeList;
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

private void themeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var theme = (sender as ListPicker);
        //MessageBox.Show("Chosen theme: " + e.AddedItems[0].ToString());

        if (themeListPicker.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        //How to save the current theme color in IsoStore?
        var CurrentTheme = themeListPicker.SelectedItem as Theme;
        //Custom Settings class to save current color in IsoStore
        Settings.themeBrush.Value = CurrentTheme.Brush;
    }
```

ThemeViewModel.cs

```
private Theme _currentTheme;        
    public Theme CurrentTheme
    {
        get { return _currentTheme; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentTheme) return;
            _currentTheme = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTheme");
        }
    }

    private IList<Theme> _themes;
    public IList<Theme> Themes
    {
        get { return _themes; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _themes) return;
            _themes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Themes");
        }
    }
```

Theme.cs

```
public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Brush
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        }
    }
```

Settings.cs

```
//Theme
    public static readonly Setting<SolidColorBrush> themeBrush = new Setting<SolidColorBrush>("themeBrush", new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 0, 255)));
```

With this new edit and setting `CurrentTheme` in the binding such as `Foreground="{Binding CurrentTheme.Brush}"` its like the items in the ListPicker are invisible, but when I remove `CurrentTheme` from the binding such as in `Foreground="{Binding Brush}"` the ListPicker items show up with their associated colors? Along those lines, neither using or not using `CurrentTheme` in the Foreground binding of the `Slider` control works, and so the foreground seems to just be transparent. Also, how can I change the border of the ListPicker in this manner when a new ListPicker selection is made? Also, I need to save the current theme color so that the items in the View will have the same color when returning to the app. What would be the best way of assigning the items a permanent color once a new item is selected in the ListPicker? I have a `Settings` class shown above which can store the brush value in IsoStore but how do I apply it to items in the View following your solution (usually I would do this in the code behind explicitly)?

Comment: To change the color of a control can bind `Brush` to the `Foreground` property of that control, for simple controls anyway. For more complex controls, like the `ListPicker` you'll have to create a `ControlTemplate` as I suggested in my other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898395/how-to-change-listpicker-selection-template) which you probably want to upvote or select as answer because you used my code in this question... :) Indeed, you should consider MVVM as @Iain suggests.

Comment: oh yes I forgot to vote! will do now! thanks.

Comment: I followed your suggestion with considering MVVM as the way to go, and updated my solution above. I do however have a question of how to save the selected color from the ListPicker and have it apply to items in the View permanently (and immediately). Also I have a style in `App.xaml` in which a property takes a color value, how would I apply the color that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find this much easier if you adopt an MVVM approach as follows.

Create a PageViewModel to represent all your data. e.g:

```
public class PageViewModel : NotifyingObject
{
    public Theme CurrentTheme
    {
        get { return _currentTheme; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentTheme) return;
            _currentTheme = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentTheme");
        }
    }
    public IList<Theme> Themes
    {
        get { return _themes; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _themes) return;
            _themes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Themes");
        }
    }
}
```

Now assign a new PageViewModel to your DataContext:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    themeList = new List<Theme>();
    themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Indigo.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "indigo", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 0, 255) });
    themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cyan.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cyan", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 27, 161, 226) });
    themeList.Add(new Theme() { Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Themes/Cobalt.png", UriKind.Relative)), Name = "cobalt", Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 80, 239) });

    var viewModel = new PageViewModel();
    viewModel.Themes = themeList;
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Now in your xaml bind your list picker to your view model:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ... ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" .../>
```

Now you can bind any other elements you want e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTheme.Name}" Foreground="{Binding CurrentTheme.Brush}">
```

EDIT:

Make sure your CurrentTheme is being updated by adding this binding to the ListPicker:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ... SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTheme, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Your `DataTemplate`s should not have `CurrentTheme` in their bindings as you have spotted. The bindings in DataTemplates should relate to an individual item in the ListPicker (i.e. anything on a `Theme`)

Comment: OK I have updated my solution accordingly, although I am still having a couple issues and questions. I added an edit above to reflect my changes. Could you offer some insight into my issues following your solution above?

Comment: You don't seem to be updating the CurrentTheme on your ViewModel. I'll  make an edit above.

Comment: OK that worked and I also removed the `SelectionChanged` event. I guess all I'm wondering is how to permanently save the chosen color in the `ListPicker` and apply it to items in the View in this page and others. I have `Settings.themeBrush.Value` to hold the selected color permanently, but where should I assign this and how is best to bind this to View items? I have a header style in App.xaml.cs which would need to be assigned the color, and other items in the View (some of which foreground is set in XAML, and others in code behind such as for ToggleSwitch enabled/disabled colors).

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you, can't you simply set the `Foreground` of the UI elements in your view on the `SelectionChanged` Event ? It will reflect the changes instantly.

```
private void themeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (themeListPicker.SelectedItem == null)
        return;

    CurrentTheme = themeListPicker.SelectedItem as Theme;
    SolidColorBrush b = CurrentTheme.Brush;
    //Change foreground of toggle switch, slider etc you want here
    toggle.Foreground = b;
    slider.Foreground = b;
}
```

If the UI elements you want to change are bound with the `ListPicker` then `MVVM` is the best way to go. Although you will have to set the `DataContext` of the whole container to your class and that will introduce certain dependencies on accessing UI elements properties. You will have to bind everything you need to the `Theme` class eg. `TextBlock`'s text, foreground etc. If you do this make sure all have `INotifyPropertyChanged` inherited to reflect any dynamic changes.

Comment: I tried your solution and it certainly worked, although I would like to use the MVVM method, it seems a lot more dynamic. I edited my solution above with a few issues at the bottom. Perhaps you could provide some insight? (I'm somewhat new to the MVVM when it comes to binding items of a class to the View).